# How to get programatically all the compiler flags set by /permissve- in VS2017 Update8.2

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017

How to get programatically,  options enabled by Visual Studio 2017 compiler flag /permissive-

As per Microsoft Documentation /permissive- flag sets the /Zc compiler options for strict conformance

Now the below code gets compiled on Visual Studio 2017 Update8.2 with only /permissive- compiler flag on , and fails when /permissive- flag is not turned on (on Vs2017 Update 8.2)

```
#include <sstream>

namespace ABC {

template <typename T>

bool operator|(T v1, T v2) {
}}

std::stringstream ss_; //commenting this removes the error

using namespace ABC;

int main() {
return 0;
}
```

I want to know which compiler flag of /Zc fixed this

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs without `/permissive-` because the compiler will not perform proper two-phase name lookup for templates.

In sstream, line 270 you'll find:

```
            …
            constexpr auto _Both = ios_base::in | ios_base::out;
            …
```

as part of the definition of `std::basic_stringbuf::seekoff()` which is a virtual member function. `std::basic_stringstream<char>` contains a member that is an `std::basic_stringbuf` instance, the construction of which requires the definition of the virtual member functions.

After including `<sstream>`, you define and introduce into the global namespace a generic `operator |` overload. The operands in the `|` expression above contain only non-dependent names. Therefore, this expression should actually not be affected by the presence of your `operator |` because the decision which operator function to use should happen at the point where the expression is first encountered in the definition of `std::basic_stringbuf::seekoff()`. However, (as far as my understanding goes) the Visual C++ compiler will effectively just put template function instances at the end of the translation unit. This in itself is allowed based on [[temp.point]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.point#8). However, Visual C++ used to also delay all name lookup to template instantiation time which is [documented non-standard behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/nonstandard-behavior?view=vs-2017#binding-nondependent-names-in-templates). Without the `/permissive-` switch, the compiler will still perform this non-standard name lookup as a compatibility feature. It will then find and try to use your `operator |` which is a better match than the built-in operator because both operands are of enumeration type and would require an [integral promotion](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom#4). With `/permissive-`, the compiler will perform proper two-phase name lookup and correctly decide to use the built-in `|` operator instead.

There is a [`/Zc:twoPhase-`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-twophase?view=vs-2017) flag to explicitly turn on this non-standard behavior when `/permissive-` is in effect. Thus, you can verify that the problem actually is caused by non-standard name lookup simply by switching on `/permissive-` and `/Zc:twoPhase-` and observing that this brings back the error as one would expect…

Apart from that, note that your `operator |` does not return a value, so if you end up actually using this operator function anywhere, you'll end up invoking undefined behavior… ;)